# How to display dynamic text together with date during timelapse?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, time, timeslider, dynamic-text

I'm using time enabled data showing how environmental risks of gas development increases over three scenarios (reference, exploration only, small-scale development, large-scale development) in four environmental sensitivity classes (polygons). Each of the scenarios has a time tied to it - from the reference 1/1/2016 (current) and going into the future up until 1/1/2050 for large-scale development.

[image]

I know how to have the time display as dynamic text, but would also like for the scenario name to appear and change as text on my map over time. For example:
"1/1/2016; Reference case";  "1/1/2025; Exploration only";  "1/1/2030; Small-scale development";  "1/1/2050; Large-scale development" as the time slides along.

Can this be done with ArcGIS for Desktop?

Comment: Just to be clear, you're asking about Dynamic Text and not feature Labels?

Comment: Well, whatever might work. I have tried labels, but I need the text to be a clear heading and not jumping around on the features as they change over time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are still seeking an answer to this, I created a point feature class with a point for each date, all points on top of each other. I blanked out the symbology so only the label appeared. I also added and calculated a time start and end field. Then I used the layer properties to enable time using the start and end field. As long as your time start and end in the point features match the time periods in your risk data, this should work as you move the slider.

Comment: Thank you! The little loop-hole you suggested works perfectly!